# what is the diffrent meaning of the different location of __strong modifier

Tags: objective-c

when I use objective-c to develop ios App,I want to know the different of __strong id obj and 
id __strong obj.I dont know the meaning of the firsrt one,who can tell me the answer?thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantic meaning of both __strong id obj and id __strong obj are identical.  The latter is the proper form but the compiler will accept either.

See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics

Comment: The latter may be the form preferred by the compiler documentation but the prior is the form actually used.